# React - JSX returned by a function doesn't get converted into a Component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to dynamically pull Components based on ID however even though my function returns the correct JSX it wouldn't get converted into a Component in my render method.

```
    renderModule(moduleId) {
        let AddModule = "Modules.module" + moduleId
        let returnModule = <AddModule/>
        // console.log(returnModule)
        return returnModule
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.templateModules.map((module, index) =>
                        <TemplateContent
                            removeModule={this.removeModule}
                            key={index}
                        >
                            {this.renderModule(module)}
                        </TemplateContent>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

My TemplateContent code:

```
    const TemplateContent = (props) => {

        return (
            <div>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        )

    }
```

So in the browser I can see  instead of the object. However if I assign  to returnModule it does render correctly.

Even though I can see the object in the console when it's created from variable AddModule it still wouldn't get passed on in the render method.

What am I doing wrong? I'm importing my modules in index.js file from modules folder.

import * as Modules from '../components/modules'

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently passing a string like `'Modules.module1'` to `React.createElement`, not a reference to the module `Module.module1` itself. You need to convert the module name to a reference on the `Modules` import:

```js
import * as Modules from '../components/modules'

// ...

renderModule(moduleId) {
    // Will be a reference to the component, not a string
    let AddModule = Modules[`module${moduleId}`]
    let returnModule = <AddModule/>
    return returnModule
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `return statement` and the `{}` for that

Try it like this

```
{this.props.templateModules.map((module, index) =>{
                        return <TemplateContent
                            removeModule={this.removeModule}
                            key={index}
                        >
                            {this.renderModule(module)}
                        </TemplateContent>
                    })}
```

Comment: @Majki You still need to do it inside the map.

Comment: to have it there twice? (otherwise it returns an error) ...and it didn't make any difference

Comment: Uncaught Error: TemplateContentContainer.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: @Majki Did you exactly use my code snippet as it is and does your `TemplateContent` actually have a `render()` method?

Comment: that was not a problem, the problem is that {this.renderModule(module)} returns <Modules.Module1 /> and that's what I see in the browser instead of the object I wanna get

Comment: you can see my code above - it does have a render method and yes i have tried to use your snippet, it broke it

Comment: @Majki Please edit your first post with the content of `TemplateContent`. How does it look like etc.

Comment: I did, very plain at the moment...it renders correctly, the only problem is that it returns <Modules.Module1 /> instead of the object

Comment: If arrow functions omit curly brackets, they [implicitly return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) the value of the statement in the body. The code in the question has the same effect as the code in this answer.